# The Old Man and the Police Officer

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, situation

An old man walks into a Police Station.

He asks for help.

> A Police Officer on duty asks a short question. The old man is scared
>   and starts sweating.
>
> The officer grabs that old man from behind and puts him on the ground.
>   Before long the officer starts beating him with his fist. Everyone in
>   the Police Station watches in shock.
>
> The old man dies.

No complaint is filed against the officer. No disciplinary action is taken.

Why?

NOTE

The old man,an outstanding citizen, had no legal troubles what-so-ever. He was not carrying any weapon.He had not committed any crime that the officer knew about. The officer did not know the old man. The officer was a rational person with solid reputation.

And NO, the officer did not go crazy. And let's say this happened in US

Comment: Is this say, in a real world? I have an answer but it’s based on the fact that this is in a dystopian world

Comment: I just added that this happened in US

Comment: ok cool, my answer was that it was in a zombie apocalypse and the old man had been bitten and sweating was a symptom lol :P

Comment: lol  lol  lol  lol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> He is having a heart attack, and the police officer is trying to restart his heart.

Comment: This doesn't jive with the story. Firstly, performing CPR is not beating someone with your fist, it is doing chest compressions and possibly other things. Secondly "Everyone in the Police Station watches in shock." indicates that no one is calling 911. Thirdly you don't perform CPR on someone having a heart attack, you perform it on someone that is in cardiac arrest, which isn't the same. Thirdly, the old man would be in clinical death before CPR would be administered, that's why it is called CPR

Comment: OK, then it was a heart attack *followed by cardiac arrest*, the policeman tried CPR but very unskillfully, the others didn't hear what the old man said and didn't know what was going on, and no complaint was filed because the policeman tried his best at saving the man.